# Can morally good actions be considered beautiful/aesthetic?

Tags: ethics, aesthetics, metaethics

Ive been trying to find  resources on whether morality can be considered aesthetic.

I found philosophers who suggest ideas can be aesthetic, so I was wondering whether something as abstract could be tied to aesthetics as well

Comment: Kant suggested that beauty and morality can be very similar in his third critique (ie. awe-inducing), Bourdieu did write about aesthetics in a similar fashion more recently. So the answer to "Can ...." is trivially "yes", but that does not help much, does it? I suggest you either make this question a clear reference-request or ask more specifically about particular aesthetic theories. Best would be to do the former first and ask about specifics in follow-up questions I guess.

Comment: Plato famously linked beauty with virtue, see [Permanent Beauty and Becoming Happy in Plato’s Symposium by Lear](https://chs.harvard.edu/CHS/article/display/6260.5-permanent-beauty-and-becoming-happy-in-plato-s-symposium-gabriel-richardson-lear). Schiller more recently linked morality to pleasure (in opposition to Kant's austere moral duty), see [The Aesthetics of Morality by Baxley](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1111/j.1747-9991.2010.00350.x).